# How to parse (non well-formed) HTML in android?

Tags: java, android, xerces, xom

How to parse non well-formed HTML in android ?

I tried to use XOM and TagSoup, but i get the following error when creating the Builder:

```
11-26 20:42:39.294: ERROR/dalvikvm(1298): Could not find method org.apache.xerces.impl.Version.getVersion, referenced from method nu.xom.Builder.
```

Must i install Xerces to use XOM or can i use tagsoup without XOM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find JTidy (http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) - a port of HTMLTidy to be sufficiently lightweight. It outputs XHTML on request

Answer (score 0):

XOM may require Xerces to be in the classpath - it may depend on the version of Java. Currently we use

```
xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar
```

Comment: I think Xerces itself is too heavy to work on android...
I don't understand why i don't find information about such a basic thing as html scraping for android...