# html to xml(parsing)

Tags: android, html, xml, parsing

is there any way to convert an html web page to xml and get data (parsing) like the rss feed?thanks

Comment: you want to convert the html to a rss feed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Good JAVA library to parse HTML, POST AND GET HTTP suitable for Mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590613/a-good-java-library-to-parse-html-post-and-get-http-suitable-for-mobile)

Comment: i want to convert html to xml and do xml parsing,as we do with the rss feed

Answer (score 4):

If the html is well-formed you can use a regular SAX parser to parse the html.

Html is unfortunately often not well-formed. In that case you can first parse the html on a server using tag-soup. If this is not possible you can try using jtidy on the device.

[How to parse (non well-formed) HTML in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805869/how-to-parse-non-well-formed-html-in-android)